# Unable to connect to the server Web development

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

i'm using sql server 2008 and visual studio 2010

i have  a sqldatasource and gridview associate with the sqldatasource

when i try to execute the program I get this message :

> Unable to connect to the server development ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page has several tips on how to solve the problem: http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/250134-Unable-connect-ASP-NET-development-Server.aspx

Google to the rescue!

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help :)